# Display from SQLite database and collection in an android app?

Tags: android, sqlite

[Click here to see the display that is related to the xml file i posted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLY6g.png)

I dont get any errors when running my application in the emulator, and there is no error message when I open the TestActivity... The problem is I cant see any text displayed where its supposed to be.

Here is the XML file of the Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relatively"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fdb913"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    tools:context="com.slbw.stoplookandbewarned.Testactivity"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.90"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.20"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:padding="0dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_score"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="SCORE"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="25.0sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="textStart" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="67dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:id="@+id/score"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.60"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.24"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtQuestion"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="35.0sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgQuestion"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imgQuestion"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.20"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="267dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="268dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="22.0sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="267dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="22.0sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_counter"
            android:layout_weight="0.20" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here are the relevant class files:

```
    public class Testactivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<Question> quesList;
    int score;
    int qid = 0;
    //static int n;

    Question currentQ;
    QuizHelper db;
    TextView scored, tv_score;
    public TextView txtQuestion, txtCounter;
    public Button button1, button2, button3;
    public static String ans;
    public static ImageView img;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.testactivity2);

        QuizHelper db = new QuizHelper(this);
        quesList = db.getAllQuestions();
        currentQ = quesList.get(qid);

        this.score = 0;
        tv_score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        tv_score.setText(String.valueOf(score));
        txtCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_counter);

        db = new QuizHelper(this);
        quesList = db.getAllQuestions();

        currentQ = quesList.get(qid);


        txtQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtQuestion);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgQuestion);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        scored = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);



        //db.getQuestion();
        setQuestionView();
        // button click listeners
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // passing the button text to other method
                // to check whether the answer is correct or not
                // same for all three buttons
                getAnswer(button1.getText().toString());
            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getAnswer(button2.getText().toString());
            }
        });

        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getAnswer(button3.getText().toString());
            }
        });

    }

    private void setQuestionView(){
        //display control
        txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
        button1.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
        button2.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
        button3.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());

        qid++;
    }

    public void getAnswer(String AnswerString) {
        if (currentQ.getANSWER().equals(AnswerString)) {

            // if conditions matches increase the int (score) by 1
            // and set the text of the score view
            score++;
            scored.setText("" + this.score);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CORRECT!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //db.getQuestion();
        } else {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Testactivity.this, result.class);


            // if unlucky start activity and finish the game

           // Intent intent = new Intent(Testactivity.this, result.class);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WRONG, SORRY!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //db.getQuestion();
          //  db.getScore(test_entry.username, this.score);

            // passing the int value
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("score", score); // Your score
            intent.putExtras(b); // Put your score to your next
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        if(qid < 20 ) {
            currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
            setQuestionView();
        }else{
            Intent intent = new Intent(Testactivity.this,result.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("score", score);
            intent.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Questions class:

```
public class Question extends Activity{
private int ID;
private String Question, OPTA, OPTB, OPTC, ANSWER;

    private int ISIMAGE;
    public String getOPTA;
    public String getOPTB;
    public String getOPTC;
    public int getIMG;
    //public byte[] getIMG;
    //public static int ID;
   /* public static String QUESTION;
    public static String OPTA;
    public static String OPTB;
    public static String OPTC;
    public static int ISIMAGE;

    public static String ANSWER;*/

    public Question() {
        ID = 0;

        Question= "";
        OPTA = "";
        OPTB = "";
        OPTC = "";
        ANSWER = "";
        ISIMAGE = Integer.parseInt("0");

    }

    public Question(String Question, String OPTA, String OPTB, String OPTC, String ANSWER, int ISIMAGE){

        this.Question = Question;
        this.OPTA = OPTA;
        this.OPTB = OPTB;
        this.OPTC = OPTC;
        this.ISIMAGE = ISIMAGE;

        this.ANSWER = ANSWER;
    }

    public int getID(){
        return this.ID;
    }

    public String getQUESTION(){

        return Question;
    }

    public String getOPTA(){

        return OPTA;
    }

    public String getOPTB(){

        return OPTB;
    }

    public String getOPTC(){

        return OPTC;
    }

    public String getANSWER(){

        return ANSWER;
    }

    public int getIMG(){
        return ISIMAGE;
    }

    public void setID(int id) {
   //     this.ID = id;
    }

    public void setQUESTION(String qUESTION) {
        this.Question = qUESTION;
    }

    public void setOPTA(String optA) {
        this.OPTA = optA;
    }

    public void setOPTB(String optB) {
        this.OPTB = optB;
    }

    public void setOPTC(String optC) {
        this.OPTC = optC;
    }

    public void setANSWER(String ans) {
        this.ANSWER = ans;
    }

    public void setISIMAGE(int ISIMAGE) {
        this.ISIMAGE = ISIMAGE;
    }
}
```

I've played around using 'static' for the display functions and variables too. None seems to be working.

Here is the DBHelper I have named it QuizHelper.java

```
public class QuizHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    Testactivity ta;
    scores s;
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mathsone";
    // tasks table name
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "quest";
    private static final String TABLE_USER = "userscore";
    // tasks Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "qid";
    private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; // correct option
    private static final String KEY_OPTA = "opta"; // option a
    private static final String KEY_OPTB = "optb"; // option b
    private static final String KEY_OPTC = "optc"; // option c
    private static final String KEY_ISIMAGE = "isimage"; // check if the question is an image

    private static final String USER_NAME = "username";
    private static final String USER_SCORE = "score";
    private int ctr;

    private SQLiteDatabase dba;

    public QuizHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
//        onCreate(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        dba = db;
        ta = new Testactivity();
        String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_OPTA + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTB+ " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTC+ " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_ISIMAGE + " INTEGER(11));";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

        addQuestion(db);
    }

    private void addQuestion(SQLiteDatabase db) {


        Question q1 = new Question("A driver who got caught on drugs or alchohol is punishable by", "Suspension of license","Six months of imprisonment","All of the above","All of the above", 0);
        this.addQuestiontoDB(q1,db);

        Question q2 = new Question("What is the fine for driving without a valid license?", "Php 500.00","Php 500.00 and vehicle impounded","Php 3, 000.00","Php 3, 000.00", 0);
        this.addQuestiontoDB(q2,db);

        Question q3 = new Question("If you are caught, how many days does it take to fix your case and redeem the license", "30 days","15 days","10 days","15 days", 0);
        this.addQuestiontoDB(q3,db);
        );

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    // Adding new question
    public void addQuestiontoDB(Question question, SQLiteDatabase db) {
//        db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        //values.put(KEY_ID, Question.ID);
        values.put(KEY_QUES, question.getQUESTION());
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER, question.getANSWER());
        values.put(KEY_OPTA, question.getOPTA);
        values.put(KEY_OPTB, question.getOPTB);
        values.put(KEY_OPTC, question.getOPTC);

        values.put(KEY_ISIMAGE, question.getIMG);

        // Inserting Row

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }

/*
    public void getQuestion() {
        Random r = new Random();
        int n = r.nextInt(20);
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        ctr++;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST + " WHERE `qid` = " + n + ";", null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            if(cursor.getInt(6) == 1) {
                ta.txtQuestion.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ta.txtQuestion.setText(cursor.getString(1).toString());
                /*Log.e("IMAGE", "I WAS HERE");
                ta.img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                int imageResource = draw.getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/"+cursor.getString(1), null, PACKAGE);
                Drawable res = draw.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
                ta.img.setImageDrawable(res);
                //ta.img.setImageResource(imageResource);
            } else {
                ta.txtQuestion.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ta.txtQuestion.setText(cursor.getString(1).toString());
            }
            ta.button1.setText(cursor.getString(3).toString());
            ta.button2.setText(cursor.getString(4).toString());
            ta.button3.setText(cursor.getString(5).toString());
            ta.ans = cursor.getString(2).toString();
            Log.e("Current Question ID", Integer.toString(n));
            Testactivity.txtCounter.setText(Integer.toString(ctr));
        }
    }*/

    public void getScore(String name, int score) {
        dba = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(USER_NAME, name);
        values.put(USER_SCORE, score);
        dba.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);

        dba = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dba.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USER + " ORDER BY " + USER_SCORE + " DESC, " + USER_SCORE + " ASC;", null);
        s = new scores();
        int ctr = cursor.getCount(), i;
        Log.e("COUNT", Integer.toString(ctr));
        if (ctr > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            for(i = 0; i < ctr; i++) {
                s.name += cursor.getString(0).toString() + "\n";
                s.score += cursor.getString(1).toString() + "\n";
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean removeScores() {
        dba = this.getWritableDatabase();
        dba.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER + ";");
        return true;
    }

    public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
        List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        dba = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dba.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                //Question quest = new Question();
                //quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                Question quest = new Question();
                quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
                quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(5));
                quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(2));
                quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(3));
                quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(4));
                quest.setISIMAGE(cursor.getInt(6));

                quesList.add(quest);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return quest list
        cursor.close();
        dba.close();
        return quesList;
    }

    public int rowcount(){
        int row = 0;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM" + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, nul);

        row = cursor.getCount();
        return row;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your Logcat error message.

Comment: As I have stated in the post.. There are no error messages

Comment: in which view do you want the text to be displayed?

Comment: @KazeNotus I would like to see your DBHelper Class or DBManager Class I assume you are using a query() or rawQuery() with a Cursor to get information out of the database table and you have two tables correct

Comment: @KazeNotus I looked at your other questions from 6 hours ago and with what you have posted I see a lot of getting but no setting. Is this a MVC type design? Where are you setting the information from your rawQuery and where are you setting the info from the rawQuery it is in a cursor yes ?

Comment: @KazeNotus here is a link that may help the DB has two tables and talks about displaying the data with query's                                                               http://www.androidauthority.com/creating-sqlite-databases-in-your-app-719366/

Comment: @Grendel I have posted my DBHelper class. Sorry it took awhile to post. Yes. This is an MVC type design and I use rawQuery(). The place where I implemented the setters are in the list<Questions> getAllQuestions.

Comment: I feel like you should take a step back and make a [mcve]. For example, `Question extends Activity` is wrong - your model class is not an Activity. Your `QuizHelper` definitely should not make a `new Testactivity()`, or hold a reference to any Activity at all... You wrote a `getScore` method, but you probably should `return` something from it

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you for the tip. I have tried doing this just now and I seem to have fixed some other bugs in my code. I'm new to SO so I'm not all that familiar on these...strategies? I don't know what you should call them. I have a question though.. Question doesn't need to extend or implement anything, right?

Comment: Does not need to extend or implement anything, yes. Also, another suggestion - make sure your Activity layout code works with some hard coded Question objects in an Arraylist before you mess with the database.